# PHP - Accessing variables in an included script from an included script

Tags: php, scope, include

I have a list of files that I `require_once` at the beginning of my main scripts.

In one of those files, I have a bunch of functions.
In another one of those files, I have a bunch of constants (which are variables at the moment, but they are essentially constants).

Main.php

```
require_once \Constants.php
require_once \Functions.php
```

From within main.php, I am able to call functions and call the constants from their respective scripts... I am also able to call functions and pass the constants from Constants.php as parameters to the functions.
However, I am not able to use functions that have the constants embedded within them. 
In other words, I cannot use the functions from Functions.php that already have the variables from the Constants.php file within the functions, but I am able to use functions from Functions.php if they do not have any variables from other included files within the function.

```
Function FirstFunction(){ echo $Constant1; return 1 }
```

FirstFunction() uses $Constant1 from Constants.php and does not work.

```
Function SecondFunction($param){ echo $param; return 1 }
```

SecondFunction() can be passed $Constant1 from Constants.php as a parameter and it works fine.

### Questions:

Is there a way for me be able to use my Main.php to call a function file and a constant file and have the function file use variables from the constant file without explicitly calling or passing them from within Main.php?

If I were to daisy chain them (Main.php calls Functions.php; Functions.php calls Constants.php) will this work? (I kind of tried this but not well enough to either trust or rule out this method just yet).

### Note

Most of the information I am able to find is regarding using variables from included files, but not specifically about included files using variables from other included files.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is here, as you haven't posted any code examples of said functions that doesn't work. However, I have a sneaking suspicion that this is because of the constants being define _inside_ the functions..?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I am asking about.
I have functions that use the variables/constants from another included file within (or inside) the functions themselves.
I can post a generic example if you require one to visualize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a simple scope issue, that has nothing to do with your include-cycle.

When you create your 'constants' as normal PHP-variables (`$name='value';`), in the root scope of the `Constants.php`, then they must be called inside any later functions, by referencing them first ... like this:

```
$name='value';

    /** other stuff **/

function Foo(){
    global $name;
    //You have access to $name here
}
```

The true solution tho, is to actually define your constants as real constants, which makes them available in any scope ... like this:

```
define('NAME','value');

    /** other stuff **/

function Foo(){
    //You immediately have access to NAME here
}
```

Only downside to true constants is, that they are constant ... meaning, they can’t be changed at a later point in your script.

You can read more about 'scope' here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

`include()` works as if the contents of the file being included are literally cut/paste into the spot where the include() call is:

variables.php:

```
<?php
$foo = 'bar';
```

test.php:

```
<?php
var_dump($foo); // notice: undefined variable
include('variables.php');
var_dump($foo); // string(3) "bar"
```

Note that standard PHP variable scoping rules apply. So if you do the `include()` inside a function:

```
<?php

var_dump($foo); // notice: undefined variable
function test() {
   var_dump($foo); // notice: undefined variable
   include('variables.php');
   var_dump($foo); // string(3) "bar"
}
test(); // call the test function
var_dump($foo); // notice: undefined variable
```

notice how `$foo` doesn't exist before/after the function is defined/called - it will only exist WITHIN the function, and only AFTER it's been included().

If you want your standard variables to be truly global, you'll have to include the file at a global scope, or declare them global:

variables.php:

```
<?php
global $foo;
$foo = 'bar';
```

and then using the same script, `$foo` will "magically" appear for the final var_dump, because it's been made global.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer.
As stated in my OP, "I have a list of files that I require_once at the beginning of my main scripts."
`require_once \Constants.php
require_once \Functions.php`
as you can see, Constants.php or the file with all my variables is included first, and then my file full of functions. I believe there is no issue regarding when or where I do my includes. But it does add more relevant information for a more complete answer.